# Algebraically Solve Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{2\sqrt{x+1}-x-2}{x^2}$$

I can solve it using l'Hôpital but just cannot find a way to do it algebraically.

Comment: What limit are you trying to find?

Comment: Limit as $x$ goes to what?

Comment: @user62872 No limit, no question. It's an easy downvote. But I'll refrain from doing that to give you time to properly ask the question.

Comment: I am sorry limit as x approaches 0, couldnt find how to edit the original post

Comment: @user62872 There's an edit button right below the tag *calculus*.

Comment: @user62872 No problem. Don't forget to upvote answers which you find helpful and accept your favorite one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the top and bottom by $2\sqrt{x + 1} + x + 2$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sqrt{x+1}-x-2}{x^2}
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sqrt{x+1}-(x+2)}{x^2} \frac{2\sqrt{x+1}+(x+2)}{2\sqrt{x+1}+x+2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4(x+1)-(x+2)^2}{x^2}  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}+x+2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4(x+1)-(x^2+4x+4)}{x^2}  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}+x+2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^2}{x^2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}+x+2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x+1}+x+2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: There's a typo in the last $\lim$. Nice answer.

Comment: I believe you left out a negative somewhere, nice work though

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{2\sqrt{x+1}-x-2}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2\sqrt{x+1} - (x + 2)}{x^2}$$

To start, multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate $$2\sqrt{x + 1} + (x + 2)$$

Comment: Thank you, I had a dumb parentheses mistake

Comment: You're welcome, user62872!

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{-1}{2})\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$, so
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{2\sqrt{x+1}-x-2}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{-\frac{1}{4}x^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{4}$$